# "community.kubernetes.k8s" can't be resolved in Ansible even if the collection is installed

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

I want to create some Kubernetes objects using Ansible. The [`community.kubernetes.k8s`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html) can do this, which is included in the [`community.kubernetes` collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/kubernetes). When I try to create a namespace

```
- name: Create ns
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    name: myapp
    state: present
```

Ansible throws an error that the collection is not installed:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.kubernetes.k8s'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/user/ansible-project/ansible/roles/k8s/tasks/main.yml': line 14, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Create ns
  ^ here
```

But it is allready installed, as `ansible-galaxy collection install` confirms:

```
$ ansible-galaxy collection install community.kubernetes
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'community.kubernetes' as it is already installed
```

My installed Ansible version is 2.9.6 on Python 3.8.10, where `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3` is set and Python2 not installed on the workstation (targeted with `ansible_connection=local`).

**What am I doing wrong?**

### What I've already tried

#### Using old + new namings

Ansible 2.9+ is required to install collections with `ansible-galaxy`, so this should work. In the collection documentation I found this notice:

> IMPORTANT The community.kubernetes collection is being renamed to kubernetes.core. As of version 2.0.0, the collection has been replaced by deprecated redirects for all content to kubernetes.core. If you are using FQCNs starting with community.kubernetes, please update them to kubernetes.core.

Altough this seems confusing since the Ansible documentation still refers to `community.kubernetes.k8s` I tried this too

```
- name: Create ns
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
  # ...
```

And to be sure

```
$ ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'kubernetes.core' as it is already installed
```

But still throwing the same *couldn't resolve module/action 'kubernetes.core.k8s'* error. Both directories `~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/` and `~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/kubernetes/` exists, so I'd guess that both (old + new naming) should work.

#### Checking the directory

By calling `ansible-galaxy`  with `-vvv` switch, I proved that `/home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections` is used. It also shows that those packages installs two packages under the hood: The old [`community.kubernetes`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/kubernetes) and the new [`kubernetes.core`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/kubernetes/core):

```
Installing 'community.kubernetes:2.0.0' to '/home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/kubernetes'
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/community-kubernetes-2.0.0.tar.gz to /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1610573465r9kd/tmpz_hw9gza
Installing 'kubernetes.core:2.1.1' to '/home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core'
Downloading https://galaxy.ansible.com/download/kubernetes-core-2.1.1.tar.gz to /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1610573465r9kd/tmpz_hw9gza
```

which seems even more confusing to me, since [the old repo says](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/kubernetes)

> This repo hosts the community.kubernetes (a.k.a. kubernetes.core) Ansible Collection.

For me this sounds like they're just changing the name. But as we can see, `kubernetes.core` has its own repo and version (2.1.1 vs 2.0).

To make sure that this directory is used, I added the following to my local `ansible.cfg` at project scope:

```
[defaults]
collections_paths = /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/
```

Doesn't made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that specifying `collections_paths` works, but without `ansible_collections`. Ansible expects the `collections` directory:

```
collections_paths = /home/user/.ansible/collections/
```

It's also nice that using `~` as placeholder for the current users home directory works, so we can keep it independent from the current user like this:

```
collections_paths = ~/.ansible/collections/
```

Now my playbook runs fine and the namespace is created:

```
$ kgns | grep myapp
myapp           Active   9m42s
```

#### Alternatively

It's also possible to install them globally on the entire system by specifying `` as target directory (`-p` switch) to `ansible-galaxy`:

```
sudo ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yml -p /usr/share/ansible/collections
```

Where `requirements.txt` contains (for testing purpose both, see next section)

```
collections:
  - community.kubernetes
  - kubernetes.core
```

But as long as there are no good reasons to install packages globally, I'd keep them locally - so imho specifying `collections_paths` to the local user in `ansible.cfg` seems the preferable solution - we also avoid executing `ansible-galaxy` with root permissions this way.

### Which package to use now?

For testing purpose, I installed both to isolate the issue of my error. Since `community.kubernetes` is deprecated, I'd prefer `kubernetes.core`. This means to change the requirements file to

```
collections:
  - name: kubernetes.core
```

or use `ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core` alternatively - but I'd recommend using a `requirements.yml` which keeps your requirements well documented and makes it easier for others to install them (especially if there are more than one).

In your playbooks/roles, you just have to use `kubernetes.core.*` instead of `community.kubernetes.*`. From my first point of view, it seems that not much has changed yet - it still makes sense to follow [the new documentation for `kubernetes.core.*`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/index.html) to avoid issues caused by using an outdated documentation.

Comment: `My installed Ansible version is 2.9.6`. Note that the full switch to collections was implemented in ansible 2.10 (actually ansible 3.0.0 meta pip package depending on ansible-core 2.10). Upgrading might save you from going around bugs that are already taken care of in newest versions.